# Netbeans 7.0.1 gui does not work

Tags: java, netbeans

I installed Netbeans 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04,after choosing design tab to use gui builder the 
designed gui freezes at Loading... and gives me this error 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal 
then the designed gui does not appear
It's like the gui builder can not reload the gui beacuse of xml problem
I tried Netbeans 7.1 but it does not have Java desktop application and i can not use it
with my projects which i created on Netbeans 6.9
any suggestions please?

Comment: For 7.1 the support for the SAF has been added through a new plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43853/swing-application-framework-support

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=653915) bug tracker your are not the first person to stumble on that error, although the OS is not Ubuntu. It might also be the case that you are missing some Java libraries which the Netbeans installation might assume that you might have.

Fresh installations of Ubuntu (amongst others) come packed with the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/). The full Java SDK needs to be installed separately.

Comment: Thank you , the problem solved by enter $ netbeans -cp:a /usr/share/java/batik-ext.jar in command line,this was mentioned in bug tracker link

Comment: @Hosam: Glad it worked out for you. If this answer solved your query, please mark it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that is causing this is due to a version conflict with Xerces. I found that if you use netbeans -cp:p [location of the netbeans xerces version] then things are good... if not it tries to include it from else where and things go wonky.